# SQL server select distinct rows using most recent value only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has the following columns

- Id
- ForeignKeyId
- AttributeName
- AttributeValue
- Created

Some of the data may look like this:

```
1, 1, 'EmailPreference', 'Text', 1/1/2010
2, 1, 'EmailPreference', 'Html', 1/3/2010
3, 1, 'EmailPreference', 'Text', 1/10/2010
4, 2, 'EmailPreference', 'Text', 1/2/2010
5, 2, 'EmailPreference', 'Html', 1/8/2010
```

I'd like to run a query that pulls the most recent value of the AttributeValue column for each distinct ForeignKeyId andAttributeName, using the Created column to determine the most recent value. Example output would be:

```
ForeignKeyId AttributeName    AttributeValue Created
-------------------------------------------------------
1           'EmailPreference' 'Text'         1/10/2010
2           'EmailPreference' 'Html'         1/8/2010
```

How can I do this using SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Shouldn't the value be 3, not 1, for the EmailPreference/Text/ 1/10/2010?

Comment: No, the first column in the output is the foreign key id, not the row id

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One way

```
select t1.* from (select ForeignKeyId,AttributeName, max(Created) AS MaxCreated
from  YourTable
group by ForeignKeyId,AttributeName) t2
join YourTable t1 on t2.ForeignKeyId = t1.ForeignKeyId
and t2.AttributeName = t1.AttributeName
and t2.MaxCreated = t1.Created
```

See also [Including an Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related) for 5 different ways to do this kind of query

Comment: if created/MaxCreated is not unique, then you still get multiple results.  can this be avoided?

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
SELECT x.foreignkeyid,
       x.attributename,
       x.attributevalue,
       x.created
  FROM (SELECT t.foreignkeyid,
               t.attributename,
               t.attributevalue,
               t.created,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.foreignkeyid, t.attributename 
                                      ORDER BY t.created DESC) AS rank
          FROM TABLE t) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Using a CTE:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT t.foreignkeyid,
           t.attributename,
           t.attributevalue,
           t.created,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.foreignkeyid, t.attributename 
                                  ORDER BY t.created DESC) AS rank
      FROM TABLE t)
SELECT x.foreignkeyid,
       x.attributename,
       x.attributevalue,
       x.created
  FROM summary x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Also:

```
SELECT t.foreignkeyid,
       t.attributename,
       t.attributevalue,
       t.created
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT x.foreignkeyid,
               x.attributename,
               MAX(x.created) AS max_created
          FROM TABLE x
      GROUP BY x.foreignkeyid, x.attributename) y ON y.foreignkeyid = t.foreignkeyid
                                                 AND y.attributename = t.attributename
                                                 AND y.max_created = t.created
```