# How to select only the latest rows for each user?

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
id  | user_id | period_id | completed_on
----------------------------------------
1   | 1       | 1         | 2010-01-01
2   | 2       | 1         | 2010-01-10
3   | 3       | 1         | 2010-01-13
4   | 1       | 2         | 2011-01-01
5   | 2       | 2         | 2011-01-03
6   | 2       | 3         | 2012-01-13
... | ...     | ...       | ...
```

I want to select only the latest users periods entries, bearing in mind that users will not all have the same period entries.

Essentially (assuming all I have is the above table) I want to get this:

```
id  | user_id | period_id | completed_on
----------------------------------------
3   | 3       | 1         | 2010-01-13
4   | 1       | 2         | 2011-01-01
6   | 2       | 3         | 2012-01-13
```

Both of the below queries always resulted with the first user_id occurance being selected, not the latest (because the ordering happens after the rows are selected from what I understand):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT user_id,
    period_id,
    completed_on
FROM my_table
ORDER BY
    user_id ASC,
    period_id DESC

SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY
    user_id ASC,
    period_id DESC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442931/sql-server-select-distinct-rows-using-most-recent-value-only . You could obtain a similar situation as that question by adding an auto-increment id to your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this should work using `MAX` and a subquery:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.User_Id, t.Period_Id, t.Completed_On
FROM my_table t
   JOIN (SELECT Max(completed_on) Max_Completed_On, t.User_Id
         FROM my_table
         GROUP BY t.User_ID
         ) t2 ON
      t.User_Id = t2.User_Id AND t.Completed_On = t2.Max_Completed_On
```

However, if you potentially have multiple records where the completed_on date is the same per user, then this could return multiple records.  Depending on your needs, potentially adding a MAX(Id) in your subquery and joining on that would work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.User_Id, t.Period_Id, t.Completed_On
FROM table1 t
JOIN (SELECT Max(completed_on) Max_Completed_On, t.User_Id
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY t.User_ID) t2 ON t.User_Id = t2.User_Id AND t.Completed_On = t2.Max_Completed_On
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27359/20)