# Select distinct rows whilst grouping by max value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I currently have the following table:

```
ID   |  Name    |  EventTime            |  State
1001 |  User 1  |  2013/07/22 00:00:05  |  15
1002 |  User 2  |  2013/07/23 00:10:00  |  100
1003 |  User 3  |  2013/07/23 06:15:31  |  35
1001 |  User 1  |  2013/07/23 07:13:00  |  21
1001 |  User 1  |  2013/07/23 08:15:00  |  25
1003 |  User 3  |  2013/07/23 10:00:00  |  22
1002 |  User 2  |  2013/07/23 09:18:21  |  50
```

What I need is the `state` for each distinct `userid` from the last `eventtime` similar to below:

```
ID   |  Name    |  EventTime            |  State
1001 |  User 1  |  2013/07/23 08:15:00  |  25
1003 |  User 3  |  2013/07/23 10:00:00  |  22
1002 |  User 2  |  2013/07/23 09:18:21  |  50
```

I need something similar to the following but I can't quite get what I need.

```
SELECT ID, Name, max(EventTime), State
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server select distinct rows using most recent value only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442931/sql-server-select-distinct-rows-using-most-recent-value-only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In databases that support analytic functions, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by ID 
                                   order by EventTime desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT
ID, Name, EventTime, State
FROM
MyTable mt
WHERE EventTime = (SELECT MAX(EventTime) FROM MyTable sq WHERE mt.ID = sq.ID)
```

Comment: Although I much prefer `row_number()`, this might perform the best under some circumstances.

Comment: Also this is standard SQL :) Row_number() is not available everywhere.

Comment: . . `row_number()` *is* ANSI standard SQL.  The problem is, no real database really implements the standard.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify what database you are using but you should be able to use an aggregate function in a subquery to get the max event time for each id:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.eventtime,
  t1.state
from mytable t1
inner join
(
  select max(eventtime) eventtime, id
  from mytable
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.eventtime = t2.eventtime
order by t1.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b913b/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT ID, Name, EventTime, State
FROM mytable mm Where EventTime IN (Select MAX(EventTime) from mytable mt where mt.id=mm.id)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91b19/9)**

Comment: This doesn't relate the MAX(EventTime) to the ID, it's just limiting to the eventtimes that are the MAX() for any ID, it would fail if a non-max eventtime for one ID happened to be the max for another ID.

Comment: @Goat CO You are absolutely right bro. I got what you said. I have updated it and its working fine now. :)

Comment: Yeah that fixes it, it's a correlated subquery now, so it's evaluating the max for each ID.  It could just as easily be `=` instead of `IN` because the subquery returns one value per ID.