# SQL server select distinct rows using values before a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There was a question asked three years ago that was fully answered so I did not want to pollute that as this is an extension to that question. The earlier question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442931/sql-server-select-distinct-rows-using-most-recent-value-only.)
.

OK, I have a table that has the following columns

- Id
- ForeignKeyId
- AttributeName
- AttributeValue
- Created

Some of the data may look like this:

```
ID, ForeignKeyId, AttributeName,    AttributeValue, Created
1,    1,         'EmailPreference',   'Text',       1/1/2010
2,    1,         'EmailPreference',   'Html',       1/3/2010
3,    1,         'EmailPreference',   'Text',       1/10/2010
4,    2,         'EmailPreference',   'Text',       1/2/2010
5,    2,         'EmailPreference',   'Html',       1/8/2010
```

I want to run a query that tells me the latest 'Created' Date for a specified REQUEST_DATE
for each distinct ForeignKeyId and AttributeName, using the Created column to determine the most recent value.

Example output for a CreatedDate of '1/4/2010' would be:

```
ForeignKeyId AttributeName    AttributeValue Created
-------------------------------------------------------
1           'EmailPreference' 'Text'         1/2/2010
2           'EmailPreference' 'Html'         1/3/2010
```

Example output for a CreatedDate of '1/9/2010' would be:

```
ForeignKeyId AttributeName    AttributeValue Created
-------------------------------------------------------
1           'EmailPreference' 'Text'         1/2/2010
2           'EmailPreference' 'Html'         1/8/2010
```

How can I do this with SQL Server 2008?

So far I have:

```
DECLARE @REQUEST_DATE varchar(10)
SELECT @REQUEST_DATE = '1/9/2010'

select t1.* from (select ForeignKeyId,AttributeName, max(Created) AS MaxCreated
  from  YourTable
group by ForeignKeyId,AttributeName) t2
join YourTable t1 on 
   t2.ForeignKeyId = t1.ForeignKeyId
   and t2.AttributeName = t1.AttributeName
   and t2.MaxCreated = t1.Created
```

But I can not suss out where to put the restriction to only include rows with a 'Created' before the requested date

Comment: You have not shown the `REQUEST_DATE` column, neither in your query nor in your sample data.

Comment: How do you get `1/3/2010` when for `ForeignKeyId` CreatedDate of '1/4/2010' in the first result set?

Comment: Tim, the REQUEST_DATE is not a column. It is the restriction I want to put on the CREATED date.

Comment: Kaf, The Data has two 'Html' rows, '1/3/2012' & '1/8/2010'. As '1/8/2010' is after '1/4/2010' it should be ignored and the '1/3/2010' selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @REQUEST_DATE varchar(10)
SELECT @REQUEST_DATE = '1/9/2010'

select t1.* from (select ForeignKeyId,AttributeName, max(Created) AS MaxCreated
  from  YourTable
where created < @REQUEST_DATE
group by ForeignKeyId,AttributeName) t2
join YourTable t1 on 
   t2.ForeignKeyId = t1.ForeignKeyId
   and t2.AttributeName = t1.AttributeName
   and t2.MaxCreated = t1.Created
```

Comment: Thanks - couldn't be simpler. For some reason I had tried everywhere but there