# Select the row with the biggest ID and a specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, greatest-n-per-group

I Have a table comments with the following structure :

```
CommentId (int), 
CommentText (nvarchar(max))
EditedBy (nvarchar(max))
ParentCommentId (int)
CaseId (int)
```

for a particular `caseId` I want to select the latest comment text as well as the `EditedBy` Column.

for example , if someone adds a comment table would be

```
CommentId   CommentText          EditedBy     ParentCommentId   CaseId
   1         ParentComment1         ABC          NULL               1 
   2         ParentComment2         ABC          NULL               1
```

now, if someone edits that comment , the table would look like

```
CommentId   CommentText          EditedBy     ParentCommentId   CaseId
   1         ParentComment1       ABC          NULL               1 
   2         ParentComment2       ABC          NULL               2
   3         Comment2             DEF          1                  1
```

This editing can be done any number of times 
I want to select the latest comment as well as the history. 
In this case my dataset should be something like this :

```
CaseId   CommentId   CommentText       Predicate
  1       3           Comment2         Created By ABC , Updated by DEF
  1       2           ParentComment2   Created By ABC
```

This is a simplified version of the problem . 
TIA

Comment: what sql-server version do you have? what did you try so far/

Comment: `select TOP 1 * from Comment hc
INNER JOIN Comment hc1 ON hc.ParentCommentId = hc1.CommentId
ORDER BY hc.CommentId DESC`

It is getting me only the first comment but no predicated.
This also does not work when there are multiple comments for a case.
I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Comment: Have a look at these questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442931/sql-server-select-distinct-rows-using-most-recent-value-only. I think they have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` for creating your predicate column. Something like this.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5c6c/2)**

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Comment
    ([CommentId] int, [CommentText] varchar(8), [EditedBy] varchar(3), [ParentCommentId] varchar(4), [CaseId] int);

INSERT INTO Comment
    ([CommentId], [CommentText], [EditedBy], [ParentCommentId], [CaseId])
VALUES
    (1, 'Comment1', 'ABC', NULL, 1),
    (2, 'Comment2', 'DEF', '1', 1);
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT CommentID, CommentText,EditedBy,ParentCommentID,CaseID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Caseid ORDER BY CommentID DESC) RN
FROM Comment
), CTE2 as
(
SELECT CommentID, CommentText,EditedBy,ParentCommentID,CaseID,
  (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN ParentCommentID IS NULL THEN 'Created By ' ELSE ', Updated By ' END
    + EditedBy
    FROM CTE C1
    WHERE C1.CaseID = C2.CaseID
    ORDER BY CommentID ASC
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) as Predicate
FROM CTE C2
WHERE RN = 1
)
SELECT CaseID,CommentID, CommentText,Predicate FROM CTE2;
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want to repeat `Updated By` for each user who updated the `caseid`, use the following `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN ParentCommentID IS NULL THEN 'Created By ' + EditedBy + ', Updated By' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN ParentCommentID IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + EditedBy ELSE '' END
```

Instead of

```
    CASE WHEN ParentCommentID IS NULL THEN 'Created By ' ELSE ', Updated By ' END + EditedBy
```

**Output**

```
| CaseID | CommentID | CommentText |                      Predicate |
|--------|-----------|-------------|--------------------------------|
|      1 |         2 |    Comment2 | Created By ABC, Updated By DEF |
```

**EDIT 2**

Use Recursive CTE to achieve your expected output. Something like this.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2c9e4/1)**

**Query**

```
;WITH CTEComment AS 
(
SELECT CommentID as RootCommentID,CommentID, CommentText,EditedBy,ParentCommentID,CaseID
FROM Comment
WHERE ParentCommentID IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT CTEComment.RootCommentID as RootCommentID,Comment.CommentID, Comment.CommentText,Comment.EditedBy,Comment.ParentCommentID,Comment.CaseID
FROM CTEComment
INNER JOIN Comment
    ON CTEComment.CommentID = Comment.ParentcommentID
        AND CTEComment.CaseID = Comment.CaseID
), CTE as  
(
SELECT CommentID,RootCommentID,CommentText,EditedBy,ParentCommentID,CaseID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CaseID,RootCommentID ORDER BY CommentID DESC) RN
FROM CTEComment
), CTE2 as
(
SELECT CommentID, CommentText,EditedBy,ParentCommentID,CaseID,
  (
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN ParentCommentID IS NULL THEN 'Created By ' ELSE ', Updated By ' END
    + EditedBy
    FROM CTE C1
    WHERE C1.CaseID = C2.CaseID
    AND C1.RootCommentID = C2.RootCommentID
    ORDER BY CommentID ASC
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) as Predicate
FROM CTE C2
WHERE RN = 1
)
SELECT CaseID,CommentID, CommentText,Predicate FROM CTE2;
```

**Output**

```
| CaseID | CommentID |    CommentText |                      Predicate |
|--------|-----------|----------------|--------------------------------|
|      1 |         3 |       Comment2 | Created By ABC, Updated By DEF |
|      2 |         2 | ParentComment2 |                 Created By ABC |
```

Comment: this is only giving me the latest , there can also be a case where we have multiple comments in a case, please see edit

Comment: can you please update your sample data and expected output. Based on your current expected output, it looks to have a single comment per case

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this method
DECLARE @CaseId [int];
SET @CaseId=1`enter code here`
DECLARE @GeneratedBy [nvarchar](max);
SET @GeneratedBy=(SELECT  EditBy from Comment  WHERE ParentCommentId is NULL AND CaseId = @CaseId)
PRINT @GeneratedBy;
SELECT CaseId , CommentId , CommentText  , 'Created By '+@GeneratedBy+ ', Updated By ' +EditBy  AS Predicate FROM Comment
WHERE CaseId = @CaseId AND ParentCommentId=(SELECT  max(ParentCommentId) from Comment  WHERE  CaseId = @CaseId)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use a self join to get the results:

find the query below:

```
select a.CaseId,b.CommentId, b.CommentText,'Created By '+a.EditedBy +', update by '+b.EditedBy as Predicate
from Comment a
inner join Comment b
on a.CaseId=b.CaseId
where a.CommentId<b.CommentId
```