# How to filter a sql request with DISTINCT and multiple results

Tags: mysql

I want to filter the results, by not showing the same `SAISON_ID`, but to choose the `SAISON_ID` that have the most recent DATE_START

SELECT `saison_id`, date_start, date_end FROM `saison`

This request give me this result :

```
saison_id   date_start  date_end
0   2018-01-05  2018-01-12
0   2019-01-19  2019-02-05
1   2018-01-15  2018-02-13
2   2018-02-17  2018-03-24
3   2018-03-25  2018-06-12
4   2018-06-13  2018-09-18
5   2018-07-05  2018-11-19
6   2018-08-28  2018-11-20
7   2018-11-21  2019-01-17
```

If I do that :
`SELECT DISTINCT(saison_id), date_start, date_end FROM saison GROUP BY saison_id`
 I have this new result :

```
saison_id   date_start  date_end
0   2018-01-05  2018-01-12
1   2018-01-15  2018-02-13
2   2018-02-17  2018-03-24
3   2018-03-25  2018-06-12
4   2018-06-13  2018-09-18
5   2018-07-05  2018-11-19
6   2018-08-28  2018-11-20
7   2018-11-21  2019-01-17
```

How can I get this instead ? (look the `saisonID` 0)

```
saison_id   date_start  date_end
0   2019-01-19  2019-02-05
1   2018-01-15  2018-02-13
2   2018-02-17  2018-03-24
3   2018-03-25  2018-06-12
4   2018-06-13  2018-09-18
5   2018-07-05  2018-11-19
6   2018-08-28  2018-11-20
7   2018-11-21  2019-01-17
```

Comment: i can not understand your question ... what exactly you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking to choose between the two saison_id "0" : I want that the DISTINCT choose the one that have the most recent date_start

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442931/sql-server-select-distinct-rows-using-most-recent-value-only

Comment: you want to skip first record right??

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand this one, can you show me an example plz ?

Comment: @ritul : Yes right I want to skip the first one, but it's just an exemple, I want to choose only the one with the most recent date_start

Comment: you can do somthing like lowest date in sub query and set it on where clouse so it will help you.

Comment: [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) does not apply to only one column but to the entire row. It doesn't work with only one column because it doesn't make any sense. Just to make this clear, `DISTINCTROW` is an alias of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: You seem to have no PRIMARY KEY. So first fix that!!!!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(saison_id), date_start, date_end FROM saison ORDER BY date_start DESC

not tested. you not using MATH operation so you don't need the group by (i mean max,min,count....) and if i am correct if you set it up by the date_start DESC i will work for you. because it will first order than pick the first but test it out.
YOU NEED TO USE FOREIGN KEY BECAUSE IT SHOULD BE A RUNNING SEQUENCE. NO REASON for it to have the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use this query to get the desired result

```
select id,[start],[end] 
from 
(select Row_Number() over(Partition By id order by [start] Desc) as Rownum,*  from @session) a 
where Rownum =1
```

In case this query is little complex to you then you can use this one also with the same result

```
select a.id,a.[start],a.[end] from @session a
inner join (select id, max([start]) as mx_s from @session group by id) b
on a.id = b.id and a.[start] = b.mx_s
```